# Transforming joint pdf from polar coodinate to Cartesian coordinate

Tags: calculus, probability, polar-coordinates

I'm studying probability by myself, and I encounter this problem:

given $f_{r,\theta} = \frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}exp(\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2})$ find $f_{xy}$

I know that, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $, so I can just replace r:

$f_{xy} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{2\pi\sigma^2}exp(-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2\sigma^2})$ |J|

What I'm having trouble is to find the Jacobian, I think it should be

$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}$
where $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Is this correct?

Comment: In the title, I think you mean Cartesian coordinate, not Euler coordinate.

Comment: So what is the real problem? What did you get when you actually calculate the Jacobian? This is a standard transformation that you should do at least one time in full details.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I did it, I got $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ but I am not sure if the partial derivatives are right. Was I right about my Jacobian for this change of variable?

Comment: @user14042 so what's the problem? After the absolute value, the Jacobian cancels with the factor in front, and you have the nice product of two Gaussians. You should realize this is the inverse mapping of 2-dim differential $dx dy \mapsto rdrd\theta$.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin The problem is I'm uncertain if the form of the Jacobian is correct or not, I'm asking for a confirmation for inverse mapping. I haven't learned this anywhere, and couldn't find any recourse to help me learn. And I don't have the solution to the practice problem.

Comment: @J.G. does the order matter? How are they specified?

Comment: @J.G. you are saying it should be $J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @J.G. it's just r. I don't think you are right about this because what you are proposing is transforming from dxdy to drd$\theta$, and what I'm asking is the reverse, the partial derivatives are reversed.